# Accessing Methods of Class having Constructor with IOptions<> in c# NETCore

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a class file: **BandUtil.cs**

```
public class BandUtil
    {
        private readonly IOptions<BandSettings> _bandOptions;

        public BandUtil (IOptions<BandSettings> bandOptions)
        {
            _bandOptions= bandOptions;
        }

        public BandSettings BandValues()
        {
            return _bandOptions.Value;
        }

        public Client Client()
        {
             return new Client(BandValues().UserID, BandValues().ApiToken,BandValues().ApiSecret);
        }
    }
```

I have another class **BandTest.cs**

In this class **BandTest.cs**, I am trying to access **Client()** method from **BandUtil class**.

I tried multiple options, but not able to solve it.
Can someone please guide me on this?

Comment: Can you share how you are trying to access it?

Comment: Can you please share how you are trying the process of  trying to access Client() method from BandUtil class in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to either

1. change the constructor name to match the class name:

   `public BandUtil(IOptions<BandSettings> bandOptions)`

   or
2. give it a `void` return type to make it a setter method instead:

   `public void BandWidthClient(IOptions<BandSettings> bandOptions)`

If you take option 1, add this in your `BandTest.cs` file:

```cs
var bandSettings = new BandSettings();
var bandOptions = new OptionsWrapper<BandSettings>(bandSettings);
var bandUtil = new BandUtil(bandOptions);
var client = bandUtil.Client();
```

If you take option 2, add this in your `BandTest.cs` file:

```cs
var bandUtil = new BandUtil();
var bandSettings = new BandSettings();
var bandOptions = new OptionsWrapper<BandSettings>(bandSettings);
bandUtil.BandWidthClient(bandOptions);
var client = bandUtil.Client();
```

Comment: Thank you so much for replying @crgolden!!!  I misspelled the constructor. I am going with option 1.

Answer (score 0):

The first issue I see is that the constructor (BandWithClient) doesn't match the class name (BandUtil).

I am not sure what else is wrong but here is a quick and dirty recreation showing how to be able to use Client()

```
using System;

public class IOptions<T> {
    public T Value { get; set;  }
}

public class BandSettings { 
    public string UserID { get; set; }
    public string ApiToken { get; set; }
    public string ApiSecret { get; set; }
}

public class Client {
    public Client(string userId, string apiToken, string secret) { 
    }
}

public class BandUtil
{
    private readonly IOptions<BandSettings> _bandOptions;

    public BandUtil (IOptions<BandSettings> bandOptions)
    {
        _bandOptions= bandOptions;
    }

    public BandSettings BandValues()
    {
        return _bandOptions.Value;
    }

    public Client Client()
    {
        return new Client(BandValues().UserID, BandValues().ApiToken, BandValues().ApiSecret);
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var bandSettings = new BandSettings {
            UserID = "Foo",
            ApiToken = "Baz",
            ApiSecret = "Bar"
        };

        var options = new IOptions<BandSettings> { Value = bandSettings };      
        var util = new BandUtil(options);
        var client = util.Client();         
    }
}
```

Here is a dotnetfiddle with the code above: https://dotnetfiddle.net/srx9kM

Comment: You can't instantiate an interface.

Comment: Thank you so much for replying @harleybl!!

Comment: @crgolden - I mocked the IOptions interface as a class to make something that was self-contained and would compile.